# Reddit API ups downs bug?

Tags: json, api, reddit

Noticed today that Reddit API is always returning "downs" = 0 and "ups" = "score" for all posts.
Example:
http://www.reddit.com/top.json

Bug?

Comment: reddit API bug reports should go to http://www.reddit.com/r/redditdev

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this was a deliberate move by the reddit team.  I think a lot of people are disappointed.

Comment: Whow... really?! Can you point me to info on it?

Comment: http://www.reddit.com/r/announcements/comments/28hjga/reddit_changes_individual_updown_vote_counts_no/